# Assignment of new value to immutable value structs in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

It is often recommended to use immutable structs in .NET programming, since using mutable structs sets one up for simple mistakes. However, when I attempt to assign a new value by instantiating a new struct, I get error C3892 in C++ yet the equivalent code in C# has no issue. This is a problem because this prevents me from initializing an array of immutable structs.

The issue is easily worked around by using a readonly property instead of a field, but I would like to know why I cannot do the same thing in C++/CLI as in C#. Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply a limitation (or bug) in C++/CLI? Is there any way to make use of arrays of immutable structs in C++/CLI or must I avoid them?

C++ Header (named "AnnoyingCppBug.h"):

```
using namespace System;

namespace AnnoyingCppBug {

    public value struct immutableType
    {
        const int Value;

        immutableType(int value)
            : Value(value) {}
    };

    public value struct immutableWorkaround
    {
        property int Value
        {
            int get() { return _value; }
        }

        immutableWorkaround(int value)
            : _value(value) {}
    private:
        int _value;
    };

    public value struct mutableType
    {
        int Value;

        mutableType(int value)
            : Value(value) {}
    };

    public value struct Class1 abstract sealed
    {
        static void Test();
    };
}
```

C++ Source File:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "AnnoyingCppBug.h"

namespace AnnoyingCppBug {
    void Class1::Test()
    {
        auto imm1 = immutableType(0);
        auto imm2 = immutableWorkaround(0);
        auto imm3 = mutableType(0);

        imm1 = immutableType(1);    // error C3892: 'arr1': you cannot assign to a variable that is const
        imm2 = immutableWorkaround(1);
        imm3 = mutableType(1);

        // The reason this matters is because I need to initialize an array:
        auto arr = gcnew array<immutableType>(1);
        arr[0] = immutableType(0);  // error C3892: 'arr1': you cannot assign to a variable that is const
    }
}
```

C# Code that does the same but builds fine:

```
    struct immutableType
    {
        public readonly int Value;
        public immutableType(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    static void Test()
    {
        var imm = new immutableType(0);
        imm = new immutableType(1);
        var arr = new immutableType[1];
        arr[0] = new immutableType(1);
    }
```

Comment: It's not a bug, compiler just follows C++ rules for auto. Using auto you're hiding the  _issue_. Compiler can infer first declaration in that context  is const (note I wrote const,  not immutable) then it's the type you get. On the other hand const in C# is a completely different thing...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I still get the same error if I explicitly declare a non-const type for the imm1 declaration, and the array also is not declared as a const array (there is no such thing as a array of const types in .NET)

Comment: `const` doesn't mean what you think it does, it is pure native C++ keyword.  The CLR has no support for it whatsoever, the C++/CLI compiler does what it can to make it behave similar, it does here.  What you are looking for is the `initonly` keyword, the exact equivalent of the `readonly` keyword in C#.

Comment: @HansPassant Using initonly is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Now I'm wondering why I didn't get a compiler error when using the const keyword on a CLR type...

Comment: And now I have the answer to why I didn't get an error on the const: it's only enforced by the compiler but never applied to the compiled code. When I reference the immutable type that uses const in C# I am able to assign a new int value to immutableType.Value!

Comment: @HansPassant that's the answer, if you like to put it into the answer box then I'll mark it the answer, otherwise I'll do that for you.

Comment: Yes, go ahead an use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was provided by Hans Passant in the comments on the question: I mistakenly used the C++ only (not C++/CLI)  keyword const as if it meant the same as C# keyword readonly. The correct keyword that will be compiled into CLR equivalently to the C# keyword readonly is "initonly".

The const keyword will only instruct the compiler to generate errors but not ever produce any different CLR byte code. In general, given this revelation, I would recommend not to ever use the const keyword in managed C++ code. I also think that the C++/CLI compiler should generate a warning, but perhaps there are good reasons it does not (after all the compiler isn't meant to be a teacher).

Answer (score -1):

I think you may just have a typo in your array creation. It's missing the `^` after `immutableType`. This works for me:

```
auto arr = gcnew array<immutableType^>(2);
arr[0] = immutableType(1);  
arr[1] = immutableType(20);
```